# Python Pandas - Merge two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
     TTL1    TTL2
0    val1    
1    val2   
2    val3
3             val4
4    val5    
5    val6   
6    val7
7             val8
```

and I want to make it like so:

```
     TTL1
0    val1    
1    val2   
2    val3
3    val4
4    val5    
5    val6   
6    val7
7    val8
```

any ideas please on how I can get this done?

Comment: do you have `NaN`'s or `''` (empty strings) in the `TTL1` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about conditional setting?

```
In [260]: df.loc[df.TTL1 == '', 'TTL1'] = df.TTL2

In [261]: df
Out[261]:
   TTL1  TTL2
0  val1
1  val2
2  val3
3  val4  val4
4  val5
5  val6
6  val7
7  val8  val8
```

**Alternatively**, using `np.where`

```
In [266]: df.TTL1 = np.where(df.TTL1 == '', df.TTL2, df.TTL1)

In [267]: df
Out[267]:
   TTL1  TTL2
0  val1
1  val2
2  val3
3  val4  val4
4  val5
5  val6
6  val7
7  val8  val8
```

Comment: Definitely more straight forward if those are blanks.

Answer (score 2):

***set_up***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['val1', np.nan],
        ['val2', np.nan],
        ['val3', np.nan],
        [np.nan, 'val4'],
        ['val5', np.nan],
        ['val6', np.nan],
        ['val7', np.nan],
        [np.nan, 'val8']
    ], columns=['TTL1', 'TTL2'])
```

---

simplest answer is to use `combine_first`

```
df.TTL1.combine_first(df.TTL2).to_frame()

   TTL1
0  val1
1  val2
2  val3
3  val4
4  val5
5  val6
6  val7
7  val8
```

---

If those blanks are actually `''` then do this first

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. maybe because I have more columns after TTL2?

Comment: It works for me.  That means that there is something non-obvious that is different between what you are running and what I am running.  That could be library versions (doubt it), or data differences (likely), or user error (yours or mine).  Best way to ask questions is to provided a snippet of code that creates the data.  This way, there is virtually no ambiguity about what data set we are working on.  I'll update my post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

yet another solution (assuming OP has `NaN`'s in the `TTL1` column):

```
In [127]: df.TTL1.fillna(df.TTL2)
Out[127]:
0    val1
1    val2
2    val3
3    val4
4    val5
5    val6
6    val7
7    val8
Name: TTL1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit ambiguity in the problem but the pandas method `stack` is used to put all values into a single column.

```
df.stack()
```

Output

```
0  TTL1    val1
1  TTL1    val2
2  TTL1    val3
3  TTL2    val4
4  TTL1    val5
5  TTL1    val6
6  TTL1    val7
7  TTL2    val8
dtype: object
```